# Paypal REST API - Payment capture response missing exchange rate

Tags: php, api, rest, curl, paypal

We have a Sandbox store account using Euro currency and configured to convert payments in the store currency.
If I make a purchase in US dollars, I would expect at least the exchange rate and the converted amount in the API capture response, but they are missing.

I'm calling the following API using PHP Curl with a fresh access token:
https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/

and I get this response:

```
{
   "id":"63F99991HX835842N",
   "amount":{
      "currency_code":"USD",
      "value":"600.00"
   },
   "final_capture":true,
   "seller_protection":{
      "status":"ELIGIBLE",
      "dispute_categories":[
         "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED",
         "UNAUTHORIZED_TRANSACTION"
      ]
   },
   "disbursement_mode":"INSTANT",
   "seller_receivable_breakdown":{
      "gross_amount":{
         "currency_code":"USD",
         "value":"600.00"
      },
      "paypal_fee":{
         "currency_code":"USD",
         "value":"23.70"
      },
      "net_amount":{
         "currency_code":"USD",
         "value":"576.30"
      }
   },
   "invoice_id":"10000000006",
   "status":"COMPLETED",
   "supplementary_data":{
      "related_ids":{
         "order_id":"EC-9F92771459179154X",
         "authorization_id":"8T758094XY4322813"
      }
   },
   "create_time":"2022-12-12T11:29:38Z",
   "update_time":"2022-12-12T11:29:38Z",
   "links":[
      {
         "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/63F99991HX835842N",
         "rel":"self",
         "method":"GET"
      },
      {
         "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/captures/63F99991HX835842N/refund",
         "rel":"refund",
         "method":"POST"
      },
      {
         "href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/authorizations/8T758094XY4322813",
         "rel":"up",
         "method":"GET"
      }
   ]
}
```

As stated in the Paypal API reference, I should see the following which instead are missing:

```
"seller_receivable_breakdown": {
    "gross_amount": {
      "total": "10.99",
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "paypal_fee": {
      "value": "0.33",
      "currency": "USD"
    },
    "net_amount": {
      "value": "10.66",
      "currency": "USD"
    },
  "receivable_amount": {
      "currency_code": "CNY",
      "value": "59.26"
    },
    "paypal_fee_in_receivable_currency": {
      "currency_code": "CNY",
      "value": "1.13"
    },
    "exchange_rate": {
      "source_currency": "USD",
      "target_currency": "CNY",
      "value": "5.9483297432325"
    }
  },
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

We tried to purchase in US Dollars on a Sandbox store with Euro currency, and we expect the currency conversion and exchange rate in the Capture API response, which are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem, we had configured the Sandbox store to accept USD and GBP currencies too, that's why Paypal did not do the conversion:

[Money, Banks and Cards -> Currency Management menu must accept only the main currency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ4Mp.png)